# using subsurf modifier to object with boolean undoes boolean

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, tools

I know what the correct answer to this is, which is don't use boolean modifiers lol. Unfortunately, I learned that a little too late... Anyway, my problem is not the common boolean and Subsurf problem where it deforms my mesh, the problem is that when I add the Subsurf modifier it just makes the shape I used to make the boolean reappear... super strange. I'm using the bool tool btw.

I'm a newb just fyi, so the topology is not what I would like it to be. still learning.
If anybody has a solution that involves me not redoing an entire mesh, I would be greatly appreciative!!!

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: That makes sense.. But there are actually two booleans, that circular cutout and the one that's glitching out. But the circular one remains intact and fine when the Subsurf is added lol. So confusing

Comment: the Sudivision Surface may create additional geometry that makes the boolean fail. In 2.9 the boolean should work better though. What happens if you move the boolean object a bit?

Comment: WOAH, that fixed it... just had to be moved after the Subsurf was added. Thanks man!! Why does that help?

Comment: because boolean can fail if some edges/vertices/faces overlap, I thought it was fixed but there may still have problems?

Comment: Interesting, the more you know. Well thanks a lot I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason might be that the *Sudivision Surface* modifier creates additional geometry that makes the boolean fail because of overlapping vertices/edges/faces. Just try to slightly move the boolean object to avoid that.